# R : How to add values of 2 separate columns if the a third column has the same value

Tags: r, dataframe, sum

I have a large dataframe like the one below:

```
 #   project  sample   count    freq    a-chain    b-chain   v
 1   house    1_1      124      0.98    ZZZZZ      tttcc     4
 2   house    1_1       20      0.02    BBBBB      xxwww     5
 3   house    1_1        1      0.01    ZZZZZ      tccct     2
 4   house    1_2        4      0.02    ZZZZZ      rrttt     1
 5   tree     B_1       34      0.45    TTTTT      oooee     5
 6   tree     B_1       42      0.51    RRRRR      vvvqq     7
 7   tree     C_2       43      0.77    VVVVV      iippr     9
 8   tree     B_1       72      0.34    TTTTT      xxttr     7
```

I need to condense the number of rows by consolidating those that have the same value for "project", "sample", and "a-chain". I need to sum the "count" and "freq" values of these rows. The resulting dataframe should have only the "project", "sample", "count", "freq", and "a-chain". I'm getting stuck at a particular line, but I may have taken an erroneus approach to begin with. Any help is appreciated.

I have tried using a combination of ddply, summarize, and aggregate functions, but the best I can do is only adding one of the two columns I need to sum.

This is the line where I'm stuck:

```
 max.count.nt<-all.tcr.max %>% group_by(project, sample) %> summarise(count=sum(count)) %>% select(project,sample, count, freq, a-chain)
```

In some of the instances, I get a "freq object not found"

This is what I should get:

```
project    sample    count   freq    a-chain
house      1_1       125     0.99    ZZZZZ
house      1_1        20     0.02    BBBBB
house      1_2         4     0.02    ZZZZZ
tree       B_1       106     0.79    TTTTT
tree       B_1        42     0.51    RRRRR
tree       C_2        43     0.77    VVVVV
```

Comment: I find a typo `%>` instead of `%>%` before the `summarise`

Comment: sorry.  I forgot to add the other "%" sign when typing it on the screen.  That's not the problem though. The original code has it.

Comment: I think you need `mutate` `df1 %>% group_by(project, sample) %>%  mutate(count=sum(count))%>% select(project,sample, count, freq, a.chain)` because after the `summarise` step only the grouping variables the summarised column is available

Comment: After the `mutate`, if you need to make it summarised, use `distinct` on the selected columns

Comment: I don’t necessarily need to summarize if there’s a better way.  I’ll try mutate. But I also need to add the freq column values and I’m not sure how to include it in the line.

Answer (score 0):

We can use `mutate` to create a column instead of `summarise` as `summarise` returns only the column summarised along with the grouping columns.  Later, if needed, apply `distinct` on the selected columns to return the first row

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
   group_by(project, sample) %>% 
   mutate(count=sum(count))%>% 
   select(project,sample, count, freq, a.chain) %>%
   ungroup %>%
   distinct(project, sample, a.chain, count, .keep_all = TRUE)
```

Comment: I’ll check in a few minutes and let you know. I had to step away from the PC to take care of another issue. Thanks.

Comment: It seems to be adding the sum of all rows for the "count" in every row.  The resulting table should just sum the count and freq values only for the rows that share the same "project", "sample", and a.chain so no repeats are displayed.

Comment: @Orion11  If you need `a.chain` as well, add that in `group_by` and then after the `select` `%>% distinct(project, sample, a.chain, count)`

Comment: Let me try this.

Comment: It's still summing up the "count" for the entire table and adding this value to all the "count" rows instead of just the repeated rows with the same "project", "sample", and "a.chain".  The idea is so I can remove the repeated rows and just have one with the sum of the count and freq of the repeats.

Comment: @Orion11  Yes, that is the reason, we are using `distinct`

Comment: I think distinct will eliminate the repeats, but I don't think it will add the count and freq column for those repeats before it drops the repeated rows.

Comment: @Orion11 Yes, if you use `.keep_all = TRUE` updated the answer

Comment: I’ll check tonight.